# Automate converting legacy .wri file to .txt using write.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, legacy

I must to convert a lot of old Windows WRI files. I got old Wordpad - write.exe, that runs on XP or older WIN.
I can't find any information about available command line options for write.exe
Only option it seems is: open file passed by first argument or print file by additional /p argument.

What I need is: automate (BATCH script) opening WRI file and saving as TXT file using write.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `AutoIt` forums that can automate a GUI program.

Answer (score 0):

install a printer: "*local printe*r" - "*use existing* " - "*File:*"
As printer driver use  *"Generic*" - "*Generic / Text only*".
Then you can "print" your documents to files:

```
for %%i in (*.wri) do write /p %%i
```

Comment: This is NOT the same as: open write.exe editor and do "SAVE AS TXT FILE" command. 
By using generic printer - the result file will include invalid characters, that comes from original WRI file. So this answer is not useful.

Comment: There is a "Generic" and a "Generic / Text only" driver. "Text only" should not generate any invalid characters. I never had trouble with it.

Comment: Yes, I tried "Generic / Text only" => invalid characters. I assume that this driver can't be used with legacy WRITE.EXE (version 3.10) program on XP. (I'm talking about older write.exe version, not original XP write.exe 5.1)

Comment: As you already accepted the AutoIT-Solution it's pure academic: Do you have some "strange" formatting in your documents (pictures, tables, embedded objects...) or just "normal" ones (bold, italic...)?

Comment: Yes - those old WRI files contains pictures and other "strange" formatting. Actually those are very old files - starting from the year 1992. I needed read out only textual info for FullText indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Created AutoIt script:

```
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <FileConstants.au3>

; http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/

Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 1) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase

Local $sWriteExePath = @WorkingDir & "\write.exe"
If Not FileExists($sWriteExePath) Then
   $sWriteExePath = FileOpenDialog("Select the write.exe path", "c:\", "Write (write.exe)", $FD_FILEMUSTEXIST)
   If @error Then
      MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "No write.exe path was selected!")
      Exit
   EndIf
EndIf

Local $sFilePath = FileSelectFolder("Select the WRI files directory", "c:\")
If @error Then
  MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "No folder was selected!")
  Exit
EndIf

Local $aFileList = _FileListToArray($sFilePath, "*.wri", 1)
If @error = 1 Then
  MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Path was invalid!")
  Exit
EndIf
If @error = 4 Then
  MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "No files were found!")
  Exit
EndIf

For $i = 1 To $aFileList[0]
   Call("WriToTxt", $sWriteExePath, $sFilePath, $aFileList[$i])
Next

Func WriToTxt($writeExe, $dir, $fileName)
   Local $pathFrom = $dir & '\' & $fileName
   Local $pathTo = StringReplace($pathFrom, ".wri", ".txt", 1)
   Local $winName = "Write - " & StringReplace($fileName, ".wri", '')

   If Not FileExists($pathTo) Then
      Run($writeExe & ' ' & $pathFrom)
      WinWaitActive($winName)
      Send("!fa")
      WinWaitActive("Save As")
      Send($pathTo)
      ControlSend("Save As", "", "[CLASS:ComboBox; INSTANCE:1]", "Text Files (*.TXT)")
      Sleep(1)
      ControlClick("Save As", "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:OK]")
      WinWaitActive("Write", "Do you want to save?", 2)
      If WinActive("Write", "Do you want to save?") Then
         Send("!y")
      EndIf
      WinClose($winName)
   EndIf
EndFunc
```